# Search in two tables with IF in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables in mysql.i want to check a field in first table.If field is not empty then search in same table else search in other table.
For Example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crm_list` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
`status` int(22) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`dateupdated` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
   `id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rec` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `myname` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
   `list_id` int(22) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

In first table i want to check if name is not empty/null then

```
WHERE crm_list.status=1 AND crm_list.dateupdated=2012-04-13
```

otherwise check in second table like

```
 WHERE test.myname='abc'
```

Relationship is list_id in second table which is the id of first table

Comment: Are `crm_list.name` and `test.myname` the same names?

Comment: No...these are totally different things

Comment: show the full query please

Comment: i am searching for query...i need some one to help me in query so how i show it?In sudo code "if a field in first table is not empty then match with other fields in same table ELSE match with some fields with in other/second table"

Comment: Is there any relation between the tables? Show output example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: YES list_id is foreign key in test

Comment: there is no list_id in your create table test...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  The conditions are just expressed in the `where` clause:

```
select cl.*
from crm_list cl
where (cl.status=1 AND cl.dateupdated=2012-04-13 and coalesce(cl.name, '') <> '') or
      (coalesce(cl.name, '') = '' and
       cl.list_id in (select list_id from test where myname - 'abc'
      )
```